# How to plot a paraboloid in Maple using spherical coordinates?

Tags: maple

I am studying spherical coordinates.

Here is the equation of a paraboloid in rectangular coordinates
$$z = x^2 + y^2$$

In spherical coordinates
$$\rho \cos(\phi)=\rho^2 \sin^2(\phi) \implies \rho (\rho \sin^2(\phi)-\cos(\phi))=0$$

So here is what I believe the equation is in spherical coordinates
$$\rho=\frac{cos(\phi)}{sin^2(\phi)}, 0 \leq \phi \leq \pi/2$$
When I try to plot this in Maple, I obtain a figure which does not correspond to a paraboloid.

The Maple command I run is roughly

```
plot3d(cos(phi)/sin^2(phi), phi=0..Pi/2, coords=spherical)
```

and I obtain
[image]

**Is there a mathematical mistake in my equation for a paraboloid, or is this a Maple-related issue?**

Note that I obtain what looks like a correct result when I use the command `implicitplot3d`:

```
implicitplot3d(rho*cos(phi) = rho^2*sin(phi)^2, rho = 0 .. 10, theta = 0 .. 2*Pi, phi = 0 .. Pi/2, coords = spherical)
```

[image]

How come plotting the implicit equation differs from plotting the equation where I cancel one of the $\rho$ terms?

Comment: This is more of a question about Maple programming than a question about mathematics, and so is better suited to a site like stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overlooked the 2nd plotting variable.

The `plot3d` command doesn't care what names you use for the plotting variables. It doesn't distinguish between, say `phi` and `theta` by name. You can use any names you want for the polar angle and the azimuthal angle.

Maple distinguishes between the polar angle variable and the azimuthal angle variable by relative position in the calling sequence of the plotting command. It doesn't distinguish them by any special naming convention.

You only passed a *single* `variable=range` option to the `plot3d` command, and omitted the second. Maple is happy to provide the second for you, and it interprets the one you supplied as denoting the polar angle which comes *first* in this calling sequence.

These two produce a similar result (yours is the first, for which Maple fills in the second range for you). In both of these `phi` is taken as the polar angle, and `theta` as the azimuthal angle.

```
plot3d(cos(phi)/sin^2(phi),
       phi=0..Pi/2,
       coords=spherical)

plot3d(cos(phi)/sin(phi)^2,
       phi=0..Pi/2, theta=-Pi..Pi,
       coords=spherical);
```

But what you are looking for is the calling sequence where `phi` is the azimuthal angle, and so the calling sequence could be,

```
plot3d(cos(phi)/sin(phi)^2,
       theta=-Pi..Pi, phi=0..Pi/2,
       coords=spherical);
```

Naturally, you could also use `theta=0..2*Pi` for full polar rotation.

For comparison,

```
PP := plot3d(cos(phi)/sin(phi)^2,
         theta=0..2*Pi, phi=0..Pi/2,
         coords=spherical, color=blue):
PR := plot3d(x^2+y^2, x=-25..25, y=-25..25,
             color=red ):
plots:-display(PR, PP);
```

[image]